# Which function will you prefer to execute system commands with PHP?

Tags: php, operating-system

like `func("rm -rf /usr/local/)`

Which 'func' will you use to do that?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to obtain.

If you want to display the ouput of the command that has been executed, [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) does the trick :

> This function should be used in place
>   of exec() or system() when the output
>   from the Unix command is binary data
>   which needs to be passed directly back
>   to the browser. A common use for this
>   is to execute something like the
>   pbmplus utilities that can output an
>   image stream directly.

If you want to get the output of the command in a variable as a whole string, you can use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) (which is the same as using the [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)) :

> Execute command via shell and return
>   the complete output as a string

And, if you want to get it line by line, you'll use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) :

> If the output  argument is present,
>   then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from
>   the command. Trailing whitespace, such
>   as \n, is not included in this array.

And, finally, if you need a bit more control, you'll use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) -- see the documentation, about that one ; it's a bit more tricky, I guess.

Still, when using those :

- Don't forget you are calling a program that has to be available on the host machine

  - This means if you are using a Linux command, your application will most likely not work on windows
- Depending on the configuration of PHP, it is possible that only a couple of commands could be available ; see [`safe_mode_exec_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir), about that
- Using this means launching another processus -- probably not that good for performances

So, I'd use those only when it is **really** necessary.

Comment: How to check apache user in windows?
I checked httpd.conf and see it's daemon,but there is no such user on windows.How to find the "real" user?

Answer (score 2):

You would use PHP's [`exec` function](https://www.php.net/function.exec). Other options include [`system`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [`passthru`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php), and the [backtick operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

Comment: Why dont you use other similar function,any reason for this preference?

Comment: There's no single right answer as to always use one over the others. Personally, I try to avoid them since they aren't cross platform. In fact, depending on permissions and configurations, they might not always work on the same platform.

Comment: I used it to do this,but failed:
exec("rm -rf F:/tmpJob/*").I can do it in command line myself.

Comment: That might be because the user that is running the PHP script doesn't have the permissions to execute the command.

Comment: How to overcome this most efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think proc_open is the best approach.

http://php.net/proc_open

This gives you far more control over input, output and let's you check it's exit status and STDOUT, which is more than most other commands for system calls. It also doesn't hold up the system while the command exits.